# GTK Issue - Cannot open display on Renesas Board ( X11 Embedded) on bootup

Tags: gtk, x11

I have created C++ application, which is ARM compatible. However, This application runs on Renesas Board when display is connected and I am able to see GUI.

But, when I run the application on boot time, using run levels rc.d, I am able to see the logs that application is running but not able to see gui. In logs its mentioned gtk:cannot open display.

I am not able to find what is issue, kindly help and provide solution.

Regards,
Sid

Comment: Is your program running before the X server starts? If not, you may need to explicitly set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to point to the X server.

Answer (score 0):

"Gtk: cannot open display" Which means it can not find display attached with device so if you have connected display you can export its address. generally it will be 0.0 So your command will be like "export DISPLAY=:0.0" if doesn't work try changing 0.0 to 0 then it can find the display. may be this link will be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

If you are starting application via script then just add this command in starting

Comment: The immediate reason for the error message is the missing DISPLAY, true. But starting X applications from init scripts is not a great idea even with that. The better solution would probably be to start the app from a X session startup script (e.g. /etc/X11/Xsession.d/).